# Why shifted predictor value would not change OLS estimator except intercept term?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, linear-model, intercept

This question comes from **MånsT**'s answer of [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/29781/when-conducting-multiple-regression-when-should-you-center-your-predictor-varia)

> The least squares estimators of $β_1$,$β_2$,… are not affected by shifting. The reason is that these are the slopes of the fitting surface - how much the surface changes if you change $x_1$,$x_2$,… one unit. This does not depend on location. (The estimator of $β_0$, however, does.)

Such question first arised when I centered the predictor value. Can someone give a rigorous proof maybe by matrix language? And how would it change intercept term? 
Some related question:
- [Show that $\hat{\beta}_0 = \bar{y}$ for OLS when the columns of $\mathbf{X}$ are centered](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/311503/show-that-hat-beta-0-bary--for-ols-when-the-columns-of-mathbfx-are)
- [Why does the y-intercept of a linear model disappear when I standardize variables?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/43036/why-does-the-y-intercept-of-a-linear-model-disappear-when-i-standardize-variable)
- [Prove Estimated Regression Coefficients are the same with or without an intercept term](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/171290/prove-estimated-regression-coefficients-are-the-same-with-or-without-an-intercep)

Comment: One rigorous solution follows from the final remark in my answer to a related question at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/108862/919: "The constant term will be the difference between the mean of $y$ and the mean values predicted from the estimates, $X\hat\beta.$"  The answer itself shows that $\hat\beta$ depends only on the covariance matrix of all the variables and that obviously does not change when the predictors are shifted.  That should also make clear that the conclusion follows *only* when the constant vector lies in the span of the columns of the design matrix.

Comment: @whuber Thanks! Can you provide a geometric interpretation for this property? I think the answer above are geometric interpretation,but I can't figure out

Comment: @whuber By the way, in your posted answer, if $\alpha$ is intercept, I think the system of linear equations should be  
$$ X' X \hat{b}=X' y $$ where $\hat{b} = (\hat{\alpha},\hat{\beta})$.  
Then after Gaussian elimination, we get  
$$
C \hat{\beta}=\left(\operatorname{Cov}\left(X_{i}, y\right)\right)'
$$  
Am I wrong?

Comment: A geometric interpretation is that the fitted value at the barycenter of the regressors is the barycenter of the response variable(s).